# .Net api access denied for Amazon QuickSight create dataset method

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I'm able to create dataset in Amazon QuickSight from cli. However, when I try to create a dataset from local system Asp.Net code using Amazon SDK then I get access denied. All the read and list methods work fine though. I'm using same aws credentials that I use for cli.

CLI Code:

```
aws quicksight create-data-set --cli-input-json file://./create-data-set.json --profile PROFILE //This works fine in CLI
```

C# Code:

```
AmazonQuickSightClient client = new AmazonQuickSightClient(<AccessKey>, <SecretAccessKey>, <Region>); //Same credentials as I used in above CLI

//This line works
List<DataSetSummary> dsSummary = client.ListDataSetsAsync(<ListDataSetsRequest>).Result.DataSetSummaries;

//This line throws error
int result = client.CreateDataSetAsync(<CreateDataSetRequest>).Result.Status;
```

The errors I see in the exception are:

"User: arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:user/USER is not authorized to access this resource"

"AccessDeniedException"

"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Thank you

Comment: I need to create RDS dataset for quicksight using boto3, can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

The datasource information was incorrect and updating that fixed this problem.

```
datasetBlah.PhysicalTableMap.Values.First().RelationalTable.DataSourceArn = <CORRECT_DATASOURCE_ARN>;
```